# Delta words between two TXT files

Tags: python-3.x, diff

I would like to count the delta words between two files.

- `file_1.txt` has content `One file with some text and words.`.
- `file_1.txt` has content `One file with some text and additional words to be found.`.

`diff` command on Unix systems gives the following infos. `difflib` can give a similar output.

```
$ diff file_1.txt file_2.txt 
1c1
< One file with some text and words.
---
> One file with some text and additional words to be found.
```

Is there an easy way to found the words added or removed between two files, or at least between two lines as `git diff --word-diff` does.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html first hit with googling "python diff"

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Vorsprung, have you read my question ? This not about delta lines but about delta words, this not the same thing.

Comment: @tristan, I know how to do a delta line but algorithms are not the same for delta words. This is why I talk about `git diff --word-diff`but this can only be used inside a git project.

Comment: If you directly provide the filepaths to `git diff` you don't need a repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to read your files into strings with `open()` where `'file_1.txt'` is path to your file and `'r'` is for "reading mode".
Similar for the second file. And don't forget to `close()` your files when you're done!
Use `split(' ')` function to split strings you have just read into lists of words.

```
file_1 = open('file_1.txt', 'r')
text_1 = file_1.read().split(' ')
file_1.close()
file_2 = open('file_2.txt', 'r')
text_2 = file_2.read().split(' ')
file_2.close()
```

Next step you need to get difference between `text_1` and `text_2` list variables (objects).
There are many ways to do it.

### 1)

You can use `Counter` class from `collections` library.
Pass your lists to the class's constructor, then find the difference by subtraction in straight and reverse order, call `elements()` method to get elements and `list()` to transform it to the list type.

```
from collections import Counter
text_count_1 = Counter(text_1)
text_count_2 = Counter(text_2)
difference = list((text_count_1 - text_count_2).elements()) + list((text_count_2 - text_count_1).elements())
```

Here is the way to calculate the delta words.

```
from collections import Counter
text_count_1 = Counter(text_1)
text_count_2 = Counter(text_2)

delta = len(list((text_count_2 - text_count_1).elements())) \
      - len(list((text_count_1 - text_count_2).elements()))

print(delta)
```

### 2)

Use `Differ` class from `difflib` library. Pass both lists to `compare()` method of `Differ` class and then iterate it with `for`.

```
from difflib import Differ
difference = []
for d in Differ().compare(text_1, text_2):
    difference.append(d)
```

Then you can count the delta words like this.

```
from difflib import Differ

delta = 0

for d in Differ().compare(text_1, text_2):
    status = d[0]

    if status == "+":
        delta += 1

    elif status == "-":
        delta -= 1

print(delta)
```

### 3)

You can write difference method by yourself. For example:

```
def get_diff (list_1, list_2):
    d = []
    for item in list_1:
        if item not in list_2:
            d.append(item)
    return d

difference = get_diff(text_1, text_2) + get_diff(text_2, text_1)
```

I think that there are other ways to do this. But I will limit by three.
Since you get the `difference` list you can manage the output like whatever you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the different methods. Maybe the 2nd one should be the most efficient in practice. The idea was to see that `difflib` iterates on something. Thats is a thing that I have just understood with your example.

Answer (score 0):

..and here is yet another way to do this with dict()

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys


def loadfile(filename):
  h=dict()
  f=open(filename)
  for line in f.readlines():
    words=line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        h[word.strip()]=1
  return h

first=loadfile(sys.argv[1])
second=loadfile(sys.argv[2])


print "in both first and second"
for k in first.keys():
  if k and k in second.keys():
    print k
```